# How to make a Select sentence with acumulate in final column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to make a query for acum the sum of one of fields in a new column, but i dont get it in SqlServer 2008 r2

I have the next table:
Fields: id,Codigo,tipo,cantidad

[image: tabla original]

I want to make a query for get the next result

[image: resultado final]

When the field tipo is 2, the acum begins

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Search for "running totals" - [over 2,000 results on this site alone](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=running+totals+sql-server&mixed=0), come back with a query you've tried

Comment: Thanks Aaron, i go to search examples

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a good sentence for me

```
with AcumulaCant as (
select
 d.idrecno,
 d.tipmov,
 d.codart,
 d.codalm,
 d.cant
from movsto d
)
select *,
CantAcum = (
select SUM(cant)
from AcumulaCant c
where c.idrecno <= AcumulaCant.idrecno
and c.codart = AcumulaCant.codart
and c.codalm = AcumulaCant.codalm),
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by codart,codalm order by idrecno desc) as rn 
from AcumulaCant
order by AcumulaCant.codart,AcumulaCant.codalm,AcumulaCant.idrecno desc
```

With this sentence i get the acum of the sum quantities by ref.

Thanks to all for your comments.